# Graphs interpretation question

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

Suppose we have a prarbola $y^2 = 2px$ ....this is in fact $y = \sqrt{2px}$, so we plot it like a square root function, so it has no applied values for less than zero. However I saw in my textbook such a plot that for $y>0$ it looks like square root function indeed, and for $y<0$ it looks $y^2 = 2px$ all over again, though it shouldn't be even defined there...how come?

Comment: Graph of $y^2=2px$ will obviously look like that of $y^2=2px$. Could you clarify what you mean to say ?

Comment: square func are not defined so that they give out y<0 , hence the question

Comment: @Bak1139 It's not defined for $x < 0$. $y^2 = 2px$ is the same as $x = y^2 / 2p$, which is defined for all $y$.

Comment: Graph of $y^2=2px$ will have positive as well as negative values of $y$ whereas the graph of $y=\sqrt{2px}$ will have only positive values of $y$ because $\sqrt{2px}$ means the positive square root of $2px$

Comment: @M.Vinay how would a sqaure of a positive number would give a negative one than?

Comment: @Bak1139 It wouldn't. But the square of a negative number would be positive. Here, $y$ is not the square, so it can be negative. But $x$ will always be positive (or zero).

Comment: Note that to get $\sqrt{2px}$, you had to apply the square root to both sides of the equation. It means that in fact, you have that $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|=\sqrt{2px}$, which is why there is both the positive root and the negative root that you need to consider. $y \neq \sqrt{y^2}$ (for negative y)

Answer (score 0):

$y²=2px$ is not an equation of a function, it's the equation of a parabola!
It's as simple as that, in fact its graph is the union of two function graphs $f$ and $g$:

$f(x)=\sqrt{2px}$

***and***

$g(x)=-\sqrt{2px}$

I hope you got your answer :)